# "\right\rceil" sized incorrectly (in Firefox 50 on Mac OS X, maybe elsewhere)

Tags: bug, mathjax

In [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078997/inverse-of-a-factorial/2079043?noredirect=1#comment4273523_2079043) to an answer I wrote, I noticed the following problem with the size of `\right\rceil`:
$$
n=\left\lceil e^{W\left(\frac{\log \left(\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)}{e}\right)+1}-\frac{1}{2}\right\rceil
$$
changing the `\rceil` to `]` gives the proper sizing:
$$
n=\left\lceil e^{W\left(\frac{\log \left(\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)}{e}\right)+1}-\frac{1}{2}\right]
$$
**Note:** I just noticed that this does not show on my iPhone, so I am posting a picture of what I see:

[image]

I am running Mac OS X 10.11.5 and using Firefox 50.1.0.

As MartinR comments, if I change the renderer from "HTML-CSS" to "Common HTML", things render okay.

Comment: Strange. My laptop (Windows 7, Firefox ?) shows it correctly.

Comment: Can reproduce with Safari on macOS 10.12.2. Setting the "Math Renderer" to "Common HTML" instead of "HTML-CSS" makes it display correctly.

Comment: @MartinR: Indeed, setting the renderer to "Common HTML" fixes it for me, too.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that there is a typo in the data file for local STIX fonts for the HTML-CSS output.  This typo causes `\rceil` not to be able to stretch past the size of the largest single-glyph version in the font (i.e., the data for the multi-character stretchy version is effectively missing).  The easiest solution, as already pointed out, is to switch the renderer, since this only affects the HTML-CSS output (and only with local STIX fonts).  Alternative solutions would include switching to one of the other fonts available to MathJax (if you want to do that, I can tell you how), or installing the MathJax fonts locally, since they are used in preference to STIX, when available.